# Entity Framework context

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an application using the Entity Framework code first. My setup is that I have a core service which all other services inherit from. The core service contains the following code:

```
public static DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    public CoreService()
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
    }
```

Then, another class will inherit from CoreService and when it needs to query the database will just run some code such as:

```
db.Products.Where(blah => blah.IsEnabled);
```

However, I seem to be getting conflicting stories as to which is best.

Some people advise NOT to do what I'm doing.

Other people say that you should define the context for each class (rather than use a base class to instantiate it)

Others say that for EVERY database call, I should wrap it in a using block. I've never seen this in any of the examples from Microsoft.

Can anyone clarify?

I'm currently at a point where refactoring is possible and quite quick, so I'd like some general advice if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap one context per web request. Hold it open for as long as you need it, then get rid of it when you are finished. That's what the using is for.

Do NOT wrap up your context in a Singleton. That is not a good idea.

If you are working with clients like WinForms then I think you would wrap the context around each form but that's not my area.

Also, make sure you know when you are going to be actually executing against your datasource so you don't end up enumerating multiple times when you might only need to do so once to work with the results.

Lastly, you have seen this practice from MS as lots of the ADO stuff supports being wrapped in a using but hardly anyone realises this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use design principle "prefer composition over inheritance". 
You can have the reference of the database context in your base class. 
Implement a singleton for getting the DataContext and assign the datacontext to this reference.

Answer (score -1):

The conflicts you get are not related to sharing the context between classes but are caused by the `static` declaration of your context. If you make the context an *instance* field of your service class, so that every service instance gets its own context, there should be no issues.

The `using` pattern you mention is not required but instead you should make sure that `context.Dispose()` is called at the service disposal.

Comment: Thanks, should I call context.dispose() in the destructor of a class?

Comment: Unfortunately destructors are not deterministic so that there's no control on when they are called. Rather, you should find one of late events in your processing pipeline and put `Dispose` there. For example in ASP.NET this could be the `Application_EndRequest` (if the data context is unique to the `HttpContext`) but of course it depends on the technology you use to build your services.